# Entire page scrolling when I only want one section to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a section where only one div will scroll not the whole page

like if the user hovers on the product images section then the product details section will stick

I don't want to show all product images to users on scroll only if hover on the product section

it's like images are scrolling on a div only

Codepen:https://codepen.io/taruunn/pen/MWONvdr

```css
 .productWrapper{
      display:flex;
  
        max-width:1440px;
      margin:0 auto
    }
    .product_images{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
       width: 100%;
        flex: 1 1 50%;
      
    }
    .product_images img{
      margin-top:25px
    }
    .product_details{
      padding:0 25px;
          width: 100%;
        flex: 1 1 40%;
    }
    .product_images:hover +.product_details .product_sticky  {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="productWrapper">
<div class="product_images">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x900?text=product-image">
    
</div>
<div class="product_details">
  <div class="product_sticky">
    <h2>product title </h2>
    <h4>Price</h4>
  <p>Product description Product descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct description </p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing will be done by JavaScript. But if you don't want to use JS then this thing you will be doing by keyframes.

```css
.productWrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
    max-width:1440px;
  margin:0 auto
}
.product_images{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
   width: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  position : relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:450px;
  
}
.product_images img{
  margin-top:25px;
    Position :absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  
}
.product_images img:nth-child(1){
  top:0;
}
.product_images img:nth-child(2),
.product_images img:nth-child(3),
.product_images img:nth-child(4),
.product_images img:nth-child(5),
.product_images img:nth-child(6){
    top: 200%;
}
.product_images:hover img{
  
  animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: mymove;
}
.product_images img:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 0s;
    z-index: 1;
}
.product_images img:nth-child(3) {
       animation-delay: 3s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.product_images img:nth-child(4) {
        animation-delay: 6s;
    z-index: 4;
}
.product_images img:nth-child(5) {
     animation-delay: 9s;
    z-index: 5;
}
.product_images img:nth-child(6) {
     animation-delay: 12s;
    z-index: 6;
}
.product_details{
  padding:0 25px;
      width: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 40%;
}
.product_images:hover +.product_details .product_sticky  {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}


@keyframes mymove{
  0% {
        top: 200%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="productWrapper">
<div class="product_images">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600?text=product-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x900?text=product-image">
    
</div>
<div class="product_details">
  <div class="product_sticky">
    <h2>product title </h2>
    <h4>Price</h4>
  <p>Product description Product descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct descriptionProduct description </p>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah its works but it kind of auto-scroll 
I want when user scroll then the second image will come only when hovering, I want scroll on image container only when user scroll outside of images next section will come and when hover on and scroll then second image will come

Comment: you need this effect on scroll or hover?

Comment: Only need when user hover on the images section

Comment: I solved this, Thanks